# "Downsample" a dense grouping of points onto a sparse grid

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, resampling, sp

I have a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` with thousands of datapoints in a relatively small geographic area. The points are grouped around regions of physical measurements and are hence irregularly spaced:

```
plot(old)
```

[image: old data]

I'd like to resample these data onto a coarser grid that is sparsely populated so as not to overextrapolate observations. Each point in the grid grid should take on the value of the closest point in `old` --- unless there are no data within (say) a 500m radius, in which case the grid point in `new` should take on the value of `NA`.

```
ggg <-raster(crs = old@proj4string,
               ext = extent(old@bbox),
               resolution = 1000)
gg <- as(pppp, 'SpatialGrid')
plot(gg)
```

[image: grid for new data]

I have played around with creating an empty `SpatialGrid` object as shown above and using `over()`, but I get a vector of NAs. I assume that's because the points in the grid do not precisely align with my data.

I am currently trying to see if there's a way to do it with `aggregate` but no dice so far. Note that I don't want to average all values in each grid cell---instead, I want to use the nearest single observation to each grid cell center / point.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You could treat this as a (degenerate) interpolation problem, using a neighbourhood of one, try something along the lines of

```
library(gstat)
i = idw(var~1, old, ggg, nmax = 1, maxdist = 500)
library(sp)
spplot(i[1])
```

where `var` refers to the name of the variable you sampled.

Comment: Thank you. Since posting, I solved my problem. I will post it here for reference. I ended up discovering `nncross()` in `spatstat`. However, thanks for the response.

As a general question: what's degenerate interpolation? Wikipedia didn't help me there? (And what, if any, is the label given to interpolation methods that are not degenerate)? Thanks.

Comment: (just edited)  - I meant interpolation with a single nearest observation, which does not really interpolate (basically spatial k-NN, with k = 1, but generating missing value if value is further than 500)

Answer (score 1):

I found I was able to solve the problem using the `nncross()` function in the package `spatstat`. I don't know if this was the simplest solution, since it required first converting my `SpatialPoints` to class `ppp`. In any case here it is:

```
library('raster')
library('spatstat')

# Make the grid. Use raster() and then convert.
# Not the most direct but it works.
gridRes = 1000 # meters
ggg <-raster(crs = old@proj4string,
             ext = extent(old@bbox),
             resolution = gridRes)
gg <- as(ggg, 'SpatialGrid')
g <- as(gg, 'SpatialPoints')

grd <- ppp(x = g@coords[,1],
           y = g@coords[,2],
           window = owin(xrange=g@bbox[1,], yrange = g@bbox[2,]))
old_ppp <- ppp(x = old@coords[,1],
           y = old@coords[,2],
           window = owin(xrange=old@bbox[1,],
           yrange = old@bbox[2,]))

distz <- nncross(grd, old_ppp)
# distz is a dataframe with a row for each item in grd,
# and each row contains (1) distance and (2) reference to the nearest
# point in old_ppp.
```

Comment: The grumpy old man here wants to edit out all the @ uses here with proj4string(), extent(), coordinates(), xmin(), xmax(), ymin(), ymax().

Comment: As a new R user this was far from clear the first time I read the rgdal / sp doc. Took ages just to stumble on how to extract information I needed from the datastructures :) Thanks for the pointer; will try to remember this!